# Making a sound bubbly

Tags: spectral, logic, convolution, sound-design

Hi,

I'm looking for techniques (in Logic Pro) to take a smooth sound and make it sound bubbly.

Things I've tried:

- Passing it through bubbles in logics "space designer" convolution reverb which hasn't worked well
- Playing with the autofilter plugin (which admittedly I know less well) and automating the rate
- Spectral gate (which doesn't work so well on such a smooth tone.
- A spectral pulse plugin I have which sounds a little too scifi-like.

Any tips on how to approach this. I'm going for something more like soap bubbles than underwater bubbles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is any go-to effect to do this, as the source material will dictate the approach and the amount of processing required to make it 'read' as what you wish... For me, a soap bubble popping is likely best emulated with your mouth, making subtle 'plosives eg saying/making only the very first fragment of the letter p from the word pop... almost just a very short lip smack open..

if instead of breath/pressure change from your mouth you want to use a continuous tone as the source then i would probably experiment with an LFO and/or a tight/fast Envelope generator - first find an LFO speed thats working at a speed that evokes what you are after when applied to something obvious (eg filter cutoff) & then try re-applying it to different parameters eg pitch, filter cutoff/resonance etc.... Some delay with (subtle or not) pitch shift in the feedback path may help too.... Or a tight fast ADSR applied to amplitude or filter cutoff

Answer (score 2):

I echo (LOL) Tim's recommendation but also suggest the use of Crystalizer after using an LFO. Available for Logic Pro. I also recommend warping and oscillating the pitch a few different ways and then running it through the LFO and Crystalizer in layers at different settings.  It should give you a less electronic and more natural thick bubble sound based on your base material.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try some grainular fx.  GRM Shuffle would get you there or the Grain Delay stock in Ableton.

Answer (score 1):

if you use multiple short grain delays you'll get exactly what you're looking for.

https://soundcloud.com/standingwave/everyday-06-23-13-voice-vocal

all the sfx during the first half were multiple short delays with high feedbacks and varying grain size settings.

Comment: this is basically what I ended up doing!